# Solve for two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have two variables $b_1$ and $b_0$ that are calculated by the following
$$
b_1 = i - p\\
b_0 = i + p
$$

I would like to be able to be able work the reverse, i.e. to determine $p$ and $i$ if I already have $b_1$ and $b_0$.
I must have fallen out of the stupid side of bed this morning as this looks like it should be simple, but I just cannot get it figured

Comment: what happens when you add and substract the equations?

Comment: @Raskolnikov Brilliant, if you want to make your comment an answer I'll accept it (cannot believe I didn't see this myself, brain must be on a go-slow!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add and substract the equations to get

$$b_0 + b_1 = 2 i\\
b_0 - b_1 = 2 p$$

Divide by $2$, ready.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how to "cleverly" approach a problem like this, then you can always use substitution: For example, from the first equation we obtain
$$
i=b_1+p\tag{1}
$$
and by inserting this expression for $i$ into the second equation we get
$$
b_0=i+p=(b_1+p)+p=b_1+2p\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;p=\frac{b_0-b_1}{2}.
$$
Now that we have found an expression for $p$ we can go back to $(1)$ and insert this expression to get an expression for $i$:
$$
i=b_1+p=b_1+\frac{b_0-b_1}{2}=\frac{b_0}{2}+\frac{b_1}{2}.
$$
Note that we might as well have started by isolating $p$ in $(1)$ and obtained an expression for $i$ first. This will yield exactly the same result.

Of course, it is much easier to just add (or subtract) the two equations from each other as @Raskolnikov suggests, but this requires you get that idea.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I'd up-vote but I dont have sufficient rep here yet :)

Comment: @Toby: It's alright. Raskolnikov's answer is _the_ answer - I just wanted to share my thoughts with you :)